# Android - JsonArray on Array without Key

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I have a problem with my retofit response. I get response like this :

```
{
"data": [
           [
               "Admin",
               "Adress Street 26"
           ],
           [
               "Users",
               "Adress Street 27"
           ]
       ]
}
```

My Pojo is like this :

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<List<String>> data = null;

public List<List<String>> getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(List<List<String>> data) {
this.data = data;
}

}
```

How i can get two this value? In this case, I use retrofit for my android app. I have search for two days. Can anyone help me? Thx

Comment: your object class is perfect !! Just call for the object class  `Example` , thats it !!

Comment: I thinks reponse string isn't json format.

Comment: if it is not json format, i can't pass the validator dude

Comment: @SantanuSur thanks man, I have do it, but can I call one by one data from that json? if I call that object, I get "Admin","Adress Street 26". can I just get "Admin" or Adress Street"?

Comment: Firstly Make List<List<String>> mainList = example.getData();
After that for getting list from each position enter
                    List<String> firstList = mainList.get(0);
                    List<String> secondList = mainList.get(1);
                    and so on. you can take it in loop.
After getting first list when you call firstList.get(0) then you will get admin only and when you call firstList.get(1) then you will get Adress Street 26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly Make**

```
List<List<String>> mainList = example.getData();
```

After that for getting list from each position enter

```
List<String> firstList = mainList.get(0);
List<String> secondList = mainList.get(1);
```

and so on, you can take it in a loop. After getting first list when you call `firstList.get(0)` then you will get admin only and when you call `firstList.get(1)` then you will get "Adress Street 26".

```
String adminStr = firstList.get(0);
String addressStr = firstList.get(1);
```